# How to call a class empty constructor from another class' empty constructor?(There is no inheritance) in c#

Tags: c#, class, constructor

```
class Bank
{
   private BankHashSet<string, BankAccount> _accounts;

    public Bank(int size,BankHashSet<string,BankAccount>.HashCallback hashFunction)
    {
        BankHashSet<string,BankAccount> e = new BankHashSet<string,BankAccount>(size, hashFunction);
        _accounts = e;
      
    }
    public Bank():this()// *
    {
      
    }
}
```

*I'd like to call BankHashSet empty consructor there.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you call non-empty constructor? Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Comment: You can also call the constructor on the same line you define the attribute private BankHashSet<string, BankAccount> _accounts = new BankHashSet<string, BankAccount>();

Answer (score 1):

You could overload your constructor like this:

```
class Bank
{
    private BankHashSet<string, BankAccount> _accounts;

    public Bank() : this(new BankHashSet<string, BankAccount>()) { }

    public Bank(int size, BankHashSet<string, BankAccount>.HashCallback hashFunction)
        : this(new BankHashSet<string, BankAccount>(size, hashFunction)) { }
    
    private Bank(BankHashSet<string, BankAccount> bankHashSet)
    {
        _accounts = bankHashSet;
    }
}
```

Now when you call `new Bank()` it will create a new `BankHashSet<string, BankAccount>` using it's parameterless constructor.